# How past svn merge info of a file is used during svn merging

Tags: svn, merge, mergeinfo

Production release branch(Branch PR ) has tags from 1 to tag 20 . Here ,Tag 20 is final prod tag

Branch A : created from  current Production tag say: tag number 1 .
Branch B : created from Branch A + its own changes
Now tag 2 to tag 20 are merged into Branch B .

i.e Branch B ----> tag 1 + tag 2 to tag 20 (from merging ) + its own changes.

Branch C : Created from production tag 1 and then tag 2 to tag 8 are merged into it

i.e Branch C ----> tag 1 + tag 2 to tag 8 (from merging) + its own changes.

Now Can I merge from branch B into branch C directly :

Here Branch C also contains B 's changes(i.e tag 1 to tag 8 )

I carried out merging but it doesn't took changes of tag 9 to tag 20 (other branch changes were merged easily with some conflicts ) .
For example a code snippet which was removed in tag 20, was still lying there after merging .This code snippet was introduced in tag 8 but removed in tag 20.
Can anyone please help on this :

1.How merge info property play its role here ? and 
2.How svn use past svnmerge info property of a file while merging that file again in some other branch.

This is very important learning for svnmerging .
PS : Please do not suggest reintegration > I already read merging best practices and following most of them according to our environment 
Thanks in advance

Comment: "I carried out merging but it doesn't took changes of tag 9 to tag 20" - show real code (merges + diffs for relevant points) or create public test-repo with sample-data - I can't reproduce your case

Answer (score 0):

> 1.How merge info property play its role here ?

Nohow. Mergeinfo in every tree contain information about previously merged revisions and sources of this merges (on cross-merges data does not transfered into new target). In you case - you didn't merge B to C earlier - mergeinfo for *this pair* contain nothing

> How svn use past svnmerge info property of a file while merging that file again in some other branch

Nohow (BTW - property of *subtree root*, not file, if you merge trees). Previous merges of `REVISION` into `ANOTHER` location have no meaning for merging into `THIS` location